# Firebase doesn't update widgets properly in real-time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've just started trying to use Firebase and I'm running into some problems. I have 3 widgets in my Activity, a switch, a progress bar, and a TextView that displays the value of the progress bar. I'm trying to use Firebase to store the state of  the progress bar, and then update its TextView accordingly in the `onDataChange()` method. It is used for the same purpose with the switch (toggle).

I got the widgets to update when I'm already in the activity, or just launched the activity with an empty Firebase, but **I can't get the widgets to update when I'm launching an activity when my Firebase contains data.** I can see what the issue is, but really can't seem to find a solution. Any help is truly appreciated.

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //Get values from Firebase
    mSettingsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // No settings data.
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue(SettingsConfig.class) == null) {
                mSettingsConfig = new SettingsConfig();
                //Change hardcoded values
                mSettingsConfig = new SettingsConfig();
                mSettingsConfig.setIsFahrenheit(true);
                mSettingsConfig.setRefreshRate(1.0);
                mSettingsRef.setValue(mSettingsConfig);
                mTempSwitch.setChecked(mSettingsConfig.isFahrenheit());
            }
            else {
                mSettingsConfig = dataSnapshot.getValue(SettingsConfig.class);
                mRefreshRateText.setText(mSettingsConfig.getRefreshRate().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

    // Sets up SeekBar
    mRefreshRateBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            String barValueText = String.valueOf(progress) + refreshUnit;
            mRefreshRateText.setText(barValueText);
            refreshRateValue = ((double) mRefreshRateBar.getProgress());
            mSettingsConfig.setRefreshRate(refreshRateValue);
            mSettingsRef.child("refreshRate").setValue(mSettingsConfig.getRefreshRate());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });


    mTempSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mSettingsConfig.setIsFahrenheit(isChecked);
            mSettingsRef.child("isFahrenheit").setValue(mSettingsConfig.isFahrenheit());
        }
    });
```

The following is the POJO that Firebase is using (mSettingsConfig):

```
public class SettingsConfig {

private Double refreshRate;
private Boolean isFahrenheit;

public SettingsConfig(){

}

public SettingsConfig(Double refreshRate, Boolean isFahrenheit){
    this.refreshRate = refreshRate;
    this.isFahrenheit = isFahrenheit;
}

public Double getRefreshRate() {
    return refreshRate;
}

public void setRefreshRate(Double refreshRate) {
    this.refreshRate = refreshRate;
}


public Boolean isFahrenheit(){
    return isFahrenheit;
}

public void setIsFahrenheit(Boolean isFahrenheit){
    this.isFahrenheit = isFahrenheit;
}
```

Comment: Where is `mSettingsRef` initialized?

Comment: Hey, did you were able to figure this out?